# Showing that a given set is a $\Bbb R$-Basis of $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$ be the unit vectors of $\mathbb C^2$.

Show that $B=\{e_1,e_2,ie_1,ie_2\}$ is a $\mathbb R$-Basis of $\mathbb C^2$.

Now, assume we want to use the determinant of the Matrix of Basis to show that the vectors are linearly independent. What I'd do is then:

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&i&0\\0&1&0&i\end{pmatrix}$

But we can't get the determinant of it. We'd need something like $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&i&0\\0&0&0&i\end{pmatrix}$

But I can't see how we would get this. I see that if we have an $\mathbb R$-Basis, that $\dim(\mathbb C^2)=4$ since $i\not\in\mathbb R$ but I can't see how we'd argue to actually get a $4 \times 4$-Matrix.

What's the proper matrix and how do I get it?

Comment: There is an obvious (and I think you are allowed to use it) isomorphism $D$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$, by sending $(x_1, x_2)$ to $(x_1 + x_2 i)$. Then there is also an isomorphism to $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$ from $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^4$, applying $D$ in pairs of two coordinates. Now isomorphisms send bases to bases, where does $D$ send the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ to?

Comment: $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ to $((x_1+x_2i),(x_3+x_4i))$?

Comment: Yes, that is the map I meant. Now the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is $\{ e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4 \} $, where does this end up when you send it into $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: Choosing $x_i=e_i$ we see $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)\mapsto ((e_1+e_2i),(e_3+e_4i))$. whereas $(e_1+e_2i))=1\cdot(1,0,0,0) + i\cdot (0,1,0,0)$ [note that $e_i$ aren't the $e_1,e_2$ from the original post]. Similar for $(e_3+e_4i)$, no?

Comment: That is really not what I meant, a basis is not one vector but a set of vectors, I think I'll just spell it out for you. So the canonical basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ gets sent to $\{D(e_1), D(e_2), D(e_3), D(e_4)\} = \{(1,0), (i,0), (0,1), (0,i)\}$, this is just the basis you should investigate in your problem (and the fact that it is the image of a basis from an isomorphism secures that it is indeed a basis).

Comment: Yeah, I think I do get that. My goal is still to be able to show the linear independenty by using a matrix representation. So basically working in the coordinate space. Thanks for these comments, they did clear things a bit up, but my confusion still isn't cleared 100%.

Answer (score 4):

The determinant of a matrix of vectors method works only when you have one set of vectors with coordinates in another basis. Checking if vectors are linearly independent using their coordinates in the same set of vectors as a basis gives you nothing (you'll always get the identity matrix).

All this is much simpler, though. You know that any vector $x\in\mathbb C^2$ decomposes uniquely as $x=x_1e_1+x_2e_2$, where $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb C$.

Now, any $c \in \mathbb C$ decomposes uniquely as $c=a+bi$, with $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

Composing this observations, we get a unique decomposition of $x$:

$$x_1 = a_1+b_1 i$$

$$x_2 = a_2+b_2 i$$

$$x = (a_1+b_1i)e_1+(a_2+b_2i)e_2 = a_1 e_1 + b_1 (i e_1) + a_2 e_2 + b_2 (i e_2)$$

The *unique decomposition* part means that $\{e_1, ie_1, e_2, ie_2\}$ is a basis.

---

This is essentially using the isomorphism $\mathbb C ^n \cong \mathbb R ^n \otimes \mathbb C$, and there is a well-known way to get a basis for $A\otimes B$ from bases of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I don't have a problem showing it in other ways. I really just want to use the determinant to show the linear independence. I don't get your first sentence. I think I know what I'd do know: We have the given Basis B. A vector in C^2 is a linear combination of them, so we have 4 coordinates for 4 vectors, giving us a 4x4 matrix. I just can't connect that though with the given e_1, e_2.

Answer (score 2):

To say that $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$ are the unit vectors of $\mathbb C^2$ means that this couple is a basis for the vector space $\mathbb C^2$ over $\mathbb C$. So, any element of $\mathbb C^2$ can be represented as:
$$
(a+ib)(1,0)+(c+id)(0,1)=(a+ib,c+id)=a(1,0)+b(i,0)+c(0,1)+d(0,i)
$$

so, since $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$  the elements $\{(1,0),(0,1),(i,0),(0,i)\}$ are a basis for $\mathbb C^2$ over $\mathbb R$ .

---

This proves  that the set $E=\{e_1, e_2=ie_1, e_3=ie_1, e_4=i e_2 \}$ is a basis in $\mathbb C^2$ over $\mathbb R$ (note that this is true because we define the additon of elements in this space as te same addition in $\mathbb C^2$ over $\mathbb C$), so we can use these vectors to find the components of any  vector to this basis and these components are four real numbers. Obviously the vectors of $E$, in this basis, have components$e_1=(1,0,0,0)^T$ , $e_2=(0,1,0,0)^T$ , $e_3=(0,0,1,0)^T$ and $e_4=(0,0,0,1)^T$ and the matrix that has  as columns such components is the identity matrix that has determinant $=1$.

Comment: Yeah, I do get that. Now, couldn't I write $\begin{pmatrix}a&0&0&0\\0&b&0&0\\0&0&c&0\\0&0&0&d\end{pmatrix}$? If so, how do I justify that I can do that? Like if you had to define a matrix and take its determinant to show the linear independence of these vecto, how would you argue? (if possible) Edit: I think my problem is this: $e_1, e_2$ span up a coordinate space of $\mathbb R^2$, adding i to it, we would get the coordinate space of $\mathbb C$, right? I think now, my problem is, that I always though that we stay in this coordiante space, but actually we expand it, by writing $\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: The components of a vector depends from the basis that we use, and, yes, that can be the column of the matrix that you write, but this come after we have proved that the we have a basis. I add something to my answer; I hope it's useful...:)

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to write down a matrix only if you already *have* a basis, and you want to compare your would-be basis to your known basis.

Is it the case here? I don't think so. You don't have a basis of $\Bbb C^2$ to refer to.

Therefore the only way to go is prove that the given family of vectors is linearly independent and a spanning set.

Comment: Why do I need to have a basis already?

Comment: @xotix Because the entries in a matrix are the coordinates of vectors in a basis. Here the vectors are your $e_1$, $ie_1$, etc. If you don't have a basis, you don't have a matrix and you can't compute a meaningful determinant.

Comment: I'm not sure if I do get your argument. Couldn't I just say "Without a basis, we can't work in the coordinate space"?